# Is it possible to use variable nested command splatting

Tags: powershell

I am just wanting to check if it is possible to use If statements to set the value of a nested command splat in PowerShell. Below is what I have currently:

```
$SADUParams = @{
Identity = $SAM
Company = $Company
Server = $ADserver
Replace = @{"extensionattribute11"="$Department";"extensionattribute12"="RESOURCE"}
}
if($PhoneNo){
    $SADUParams["OfficePhone"] = $PhoneNo
}
Set-ADUser @SADUParams
```

What I would like to also do is update `ExtensionAttribute12` using an *if statement* like with the phone number in the example above.

Is this possible, and if so, how do I code it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just simple access the desired property from the `$SADUParams` hashtable and update it:

```
if ($true <#yourcondition#>)
{
    $SADUParams.Replace.extensionattribute12 = "your_new_value"
}
```

Comment: That was so simple, I don't know why I didn't think of that. I think I was distracted by the solution of the previous issue which is why I have it like: $SADUParams["OfficePhone"] instead of $SADUParams.OfficePhone